# Angular - Problema de asincronía con la api de Google Maps (Reverse Geocode)

Tags: angular, google-api, asincronismo

El problema es que mi código no espera a a la resolución de la promesa que envuelve la llamada al API de Google Maps, específicamente para el tema de Reverse Geocode.

Así tengo el código:

```js
delayFactor = 0

  AddresReference(Lat, Long): Promise<any> {

    const elgeoestecsm = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lat),parseFloat(Long))
    let request = {
         location: latlng 
       }
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(Lat == null || Long == null ){
        resolve("Sin localización")
      }

      elgeoestecsm.geocode(request, (results,status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          const elretornope = results[0].formatted_address
          resolve(elretornope)
        } else if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          this.delayFactor++
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.AddresReference(Lat,Long)
          }, this.delayFactor*1000);
        }
        else{
          reject(new Error(status))
        }
      })
    })
  }


  getReference = async(Lat, Long) => {
    const apla =  await this.AddresReference(Lat,Long)
    console.log(apla)
    return apla
  }
```

Cuando doy click en el botón para llamar a esta función (cabe destacar que el botón lo que hace es armar un Excel y lo descarga en automático):

```js
this.data.forEach( async (s)=> {

        console.log(s)

        let fechaHoraSalidaFormat = this.datePipe.transform(s.FechaHoraSalida, 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss a')
        let fechaHoraLlegadaFormat = this.datePipe.transform(s.FechaHoraLlegada, 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss a')

        sheet.addRow({
          Programacion: s.OperacionProgramacion, 
          CodigoOperacion: s.CodigoOperacion,
          FechaInicioViaje: fechaHoraSalidaFormat,
          FechaFinViaje: fechaHoraLlegadaFormat == null ? '-' : fechaHoraLlegadaFormat, 
          Ruta: s.Ruta,
          Origen: s.Origen,
          Destino: s.Destino,
          Tracto: s.Placas,
          Remolque: s.Remolque,
          Conductor: s.ConductorName, 
          NombreCliente: s.NombreCliente,
          Servicio: s.Servicio, 
          Estado: s.Estado,
          LastPoint: await this.getReference(s.Lat,s.Long),
          MotivoCancelacion: s.MotivoCancelacion,
        })

      })

workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(dataReporte => {
        const blob = new Blob([dataReporte], { type: this.blobType });
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, this.excelFileName);
      });
```

La lógica que manejo es que en el bucle del ForEach por cada ítem primero imprime el console.log y luego esperará la resolución de la promesa cuando esté intentando añadir la row a la hoja de cálculo... pero pasa lo siguiente:

[image: Foto1]

Se imprimen todos los ítems, se exporta el excel y recién ahí espera la resolución uno a uno de las promesas. Qué puedo hacer ahí? Agradecería la ayuda!

Sldos.

Comment: Confirma qué datos tienes con otro par de `console.log(s.Lat)` y `console.log(s.Long)`.

Comment: Pues algunos son nulos y otros tienen valor, por eso el error de invalid latlng, es lo normal.